# jQuery bootstrap-datetimepicker change event

Tags: jquery, onchange, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using [bootstrap-datetimepicker plugin from Jonathan Peterson](http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/) on my project.

I'm having a problem with **change event** :

If I define event like this :

```
$('#Release').on('dp.change', function(e){ console.log(e.date()); })
```

I get the error :

> Uncaught TypeError: e.date is not a function

Anyone knows how to get new **date value** on change event ?

Comment: Check manual here http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: See an example here https://sourcecodezoneseven.blogspot.com/2019/06/bootstrap-datetimepicker-events-example.html

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65575015/5840973

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Looking at that link, it appears you are very close. You need to remove the parenthesis to get the right value.The way you currently are trying to log the value makes the browser think it needs to call a function.

```
$('#Release').on('dp.change', function(e){ console.log(e.date); })
```

Comment: Reference: [https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Events/#dpchange)

Comment: See an example here https://sourcecodezoneseven.blogspot.com/2019/06/bootstrap-datetimepicker-events-example.html

Answer (score 17):

Please use this code to get change event of datetimepicker:

```
 $('.datepicker').datetimepicker(
    { format: 'MM/DD/YYYY' }).on('dp.change', function (e) {  });
```

Answer (score 15):

Thanks to Kenneth suggestion, I figured out :

```
$('#Release').on('dp.change', function(e){ 
    var formatedValue = e.date.format(e.date._f);
    console.log(formatedValue);
})
```

Thank you Kenneth :)

Comment: e.date._i  << as text