# Bootstrap Datetimepicker change event is not firing

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Bootstrap Datetimepicker  change event is not firing without errors. Any clue?

https://github.com/Eonasdan/bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/docs/Events.md

```
$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker();

$('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker().on('change', function (ev) {
                alert('!!!');

});
```

Comment: Type `console.log("execute");` next to your code and check if it executes. If not - you did not add your JS script.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I found the solution

```
  $('#datetimepickerStart').datetimepicker().on('dp.change', function (event) {
                alert('!!!');
            });
```

Comment: Saved me. Thanks a lot

Comment: Nice, You saved my time.

Comment: It would be great if is there is any explantion for the 'dp.change'

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="input-group date" id="dateOfBirth" data-target-input="nearest">
    <input type="text" class="form-control datetimepicker-input"
        data-target="#dateOfBirth" placeholder="Select DOB.." />
    <div class="input-group-append" data-target="#dateOfBirth"
        data-toggle="datetimepicker">
        <div class="input-group-text"> <i class="fa fa-calendar"> </i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



$("#dateOfBirth").on("change.datetimepicker", ({date}) => {
    var dob = $("#dateOfBirth").find("input").val();
    console.log(dob);
})
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

following method worked for me. I am using bootstrap datepicker

```
$('.date-range-filter').on('change dp.change', function(e){
    alert('changed');
    });
```