# date and time filtering not working for date of datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, bootstrap-datetimepicker

Below is the code I've written. Here what I am doing is based on from and to dates selection from bootstrap datetimepickers, I am filtering the table rows. But I don't know, search is not happening here!!!... What I am doing wrong in the below code

```js
$(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
  });

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
  });

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var min = $('#mindate').val();
      var max = $('#maxdate').val();
      var startDate = new Date(data[1]);
      if (min == null && max == null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
        return true;
      }
      if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );


  $("#mindate").on({
    onSelect: function() {
      table.draw();
    },
  });
  $("#mindate").on({
    onSelect: function() {
      table.draw();
    },
  });

  $('#mindate, #mindate').change(function() {
    table.draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.2/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.2/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-6 selectpicker form-group">
  <label>From Date:</label>
  <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="mindate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 selectpicker form-group">
  <label>To Date:</label>
  <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker2">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="maxdate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>From Date</th>
      <th>To Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-10 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-12 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-8 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-9 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-15 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-16 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-4 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-5 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

For the reference check the following link [Filtering data programatically](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html)

The code `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push()` is the filtering function, which is not working, mean search is not happening!!!

Comment: What does "This code is not working" mean? What does it do/not do?

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR saying its urgent (even in disguised form) 2 minutes after you asked the question won't make help happen faster. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569. Better make your question more clear. See Hulk's comment.

Comment: Above javascript code is wrong...i'm trying to filter date and time using datetimepicker...

Comment: The respective link might helpful to you https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR I've edited your question, approve that edit, so **SO Guys** will come to know what you are trying to do!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try with [dp.change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31858920/jquery-bootstrap-datetimepicker-change-event) event for bootstrap datetimepicker. Working example is below. After change in datepicker, click on any `Column header` of Datatable. Then it will show filtered data. That might be the issue with Datatable or might be with the code you/I wrote. But filtering is happening.

Also, assign `null` to `max` and `min` variables, if no dates are selected in `from` and `to` datepickers

```js
$(function() {

  var table = $('#example').DataTable();

  $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
  });

  $('#datetimepicker2').datetimepicker({
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
  });

  $('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function() {
    table.draw();
  });

  $('#datetimepicker2').on('dp.change', function() {
    table.draw();
  });

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
      var min = $('#mindate').val() ? new Date($('#mindate').val()) : null;
      var max = $('#maxdate').val() ? new Date($('#maxdate').val()) : null;
      var startDate = new Date(data[0]);
      var endDate = new Date(data[1]);
      if (min == null && max == null) {
        return true;
      }
      if (min == null && startDate <= max) {
        return true;
      }
      if (max == null && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      if (startDate <= max && startDate >= min) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.2/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datetimepicker/3.1.2/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-xs-6 selectpicker form-group">
  <label>From Date:</label>
  <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="mindate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 selectpicker form-group">
  <label>To Date:</label>
  <div class='input-group date' id="datetimepicker2">
    <input type='text' class="form-control" id="maxdate" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
  </div>
</div>

<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>From Date</th>
      <th>To Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-10 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-12 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-08 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-09 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-15 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-16 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2018-08-04 20:13:22</td>
      <td>2018-08-05 20:13:22</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

I'm able to fix the table refreshing issue. That's not exactly with Datatables, with bootstrap datetimepicker itself. I've changed the code from

`$('#mindate').on('dp.change', function() {` **to** `$('#datetimepicker1').on('dp.change', function() {`

and

`$('#maxdate').on('dp.change', function() {` **to** `$('#datetimepicker2').on('dp.change', function() {`

Now the solution is working fine

Comment: @KIRANKUMAR glat to hear that. If this answer helped you. Please upvote and approve. Thank you ;-)